# Quicksort with Hoare partition

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I've implemented a quicksort in C++ after reading the Wikipedia article on it. Just trying to refresh my memory from school in prep for interviews for a job change.

Here is my implementation

```
#include <vector>

size_t partition(std::vector<int> & inputs, size_t leftIndex, size_t rightIndex)
{
    int pivotValue = inputs[leftIndex];
    size_t i = leftIndex - 1;
    size_t j = rightIndex + 1;

    while (true)
    {
        while (inputs[++i] < pivotValue);
        while (inputs[--j] > pivotValue);

        if (i >= j)
        {
            return j;
        }

        std::iter_swap(inputs.begin() + i, inputs.begin() + j);
    }

    return 0;
}

void sort(std::vector<int> & inputs, size_t leftIndex, size_t rightIndex)
{
    if (leftIndex < rightIndex)
    {
        size_t pivot = partition(inputs, leftIndex, rightIndex);
        sort(inputs, leftIndex, pivot);
        sort(inputs, pivot + 1, rightIndex);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> inputs = { 3,7,1,2,9,5,4,0,8,6 };
    sort(inputs, 0, inputs.size() - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work fine for all my test inputs that I've come up with so far.

*Editing from here for clarity*

If we change

```
        if (i >= j)
        {
            return j;
        }
```

to

```
        if (i > j)
        {
            return j;
        }
        else if(i == j)
        {
            return j;
        }
```

My question is, what set of inputs would exercise the following block of the partition function?

```
        if (i > j)
        {
            return j;
        }
```

Comment: eventually as the section of the array you are pivoting gets smaller and smaller, `i >= j` will trigger.

Comment: Marginally related: Think you want  `do`/`while` instead of plain old `while` at `while (inputs[i] < pivotValue)` in Hoare partition.

Comment: The most immediate trip would be an already-sorted sequence of two elements. But, if you instrument your code you'll find you're already tripping it with your current sequence.

Comment: @user4581301 Why would I want a do while instead of a while? Is any efficiency gained? Is a bug fixed?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz 'd do it for purely pedantic reasons to start. If your goal is to implement Hoare partition and you do something different, then you failed to accomplish the goal. Hoare partition increments/decrements, then tests, resulting in a minimum of one `i++` and `j--`.  A perfect use case for `do`/`while` over `while`. There will be a difference in the outcome. What the outcome of this change is noticeable difference in the output or the speed of the algorithm, I'd have to poke at if for a while. I can imagine cases that devolve into an infinite loop because `if (i >= j)` isn't true.

Comment: Look at the wiki article again, note that it starts with i = leftIndex -1 and j = rightIndex + 1, then in the loops i is pre-incremented and j is pre-decremented. It's not a big deal, but it is how wiki defines Hoare partition scheme.

Comment: @rcgldr I have and did the first time. My question is, what's the advantage of doing it that way vs the way I did it? i see none. I think the way it was written in the Wiki article is just "worse" because its harder to read. Start at the bounds and move inward. Both do that AFAICT. I don't want to implement something the same way someone else did without an actual reason to.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz - The pre-decrement and pre-increment may be a bit faster, depending on the processor, but the main point is that this is apparently how Hoare partition scheme is defined.

Comment: @rcgldr & user4581301 meh. I don't think the the details of how an algorithm is implemented in psuedocode on wikipedia define a particular algorithm. An algorithm is defined by breaking a problem into particular steps. How you implement those individual steps is completely up to you as long as the end result, and efficiency in obtaining it, are the same. Looking at my code and the code on wikipedia, I see no difference in the result or the efficiency. Quite frankly I think starting at 1 outside the bounds, only to restructure into a do while instead of a while, is quite frankly, silliness.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz - it's not a do while. The whiles become `while(inputs[++i] < pivotValue);` and `while(inputs[--j] > pivotValue);`. In the case of Visual Studio, although it doesn't make sense, typically do{}while() is a bit slower than while(). Now this could have been bad luck due to where the loop is located. I'd have to look this up, but I think other articles and old text books about Hoare partition are the same as the wiki article.

Comment: I see no difference in the outcome or the efficiency, so I have no concern.

Comment: OK. A useful set of examples: Your code with a simple inputs that cause infinite loop: https://ideone.com/H8ksmI . Same inputs with canonical Hoare partition: https://ideone.com/nv544t . Canonical inputs with your inputs https://ideone.com/qfx3us

Comment: @user4581301 I concede. Changing to do/while

Comment: So, if w had to put it in words, why we want to increment or decrement before the evaluation, we would say, "In order to move past the values we just swapped", right?

Comment: I think there's a bug when sorting `{0, 1, 0}`...

Comment: 0,1,0 seems to work OK, with the current revision.

Comment: Do you want the whole set of inputs or one input is enough?

Comment: "for all my test inputs that I've come up with so far". You could test this on all possible permutations of, say, a 10 element array. You can use stand library sort as a comparison. Exhaustive and randomized testing are useful when you have an implementation that is known to be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion arose, because I had implemented the algorithm wrong. As a couple users pointed out in the comments to the original question (before edits), the listing on wikipedia uses a do/while as opposed to a while, such that the increment of i and decrement of j occur before the evaluation of the condition.

I had assumed there was no functional difference, but there is.

So, given an equivalent partition function:

```
size_t partition(std::vector<int> & inputs, size_t leftIndex, size_t rightIndex)
{
    int pivotValue = inputs[leftIndex];
    size_t i = leftIndex - 1;
    size_t j = rightIndex + 1;

    while (true)
    {
        while (inputs[++i] < pivotValue);
        while (inputs[--j] > pivotValue);

        if (i >= j)
        {
            return j;
        }

        std::iter_swap(inputs.begin() + i, inputs.begin() + j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It becomes obvious that the check for i >= j will get a true hit after the loop walked the marker at each bound closer towards the middle, when they are pointed to the same element or have crossed over each other.

With the fixes increment and decrement loops, an increment and decrement occur each iteration of the main loop. Whereas before, they didn't.

As always, when dealing with algorithms, step through it on paper and it will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `break` in the body of your `while (true) { ... }`, so anything after it is unreachable.

As your test cases run to completion, and there are no exceptions thrown or caught, that means they must have *all* hit `return j;`, *each time* you `partition`ed.

Comment: Let me rephrase....
What are the inputs where this evaluation is true for i > j, rather than i == j?